# Segmentation fault on passing arguments to main

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, gdb

I know this is kinda basics, but i'm stuck at this.
I've been trying to make a sudoku game. The arguments would by given by passing them to the main. When trying to write them in a different array, than the **argv one, it is giving me a segmentation fault when increment an integer variable.

```
int **ft_copy_sudoku(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int **sudoku_arr;
    int index;
    int s_index;
    int j;

    printf("%d", argc);
    sudoku_arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int) * 9 * 9);
    index = 1;
    while (index < argc)
    {
        j = 0;
        s_index = 0;
        //sudoku_array[s_index] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 9);
        while (j < 9)
        {
            if (argv[index][j] >= '1' && argv[index][j] <= '9')
                sudoku_arr[s_index][j] = argv[index][j] - '0';
            else
                argv[index][j] = 0;
            j++;
            s_index++;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return sudoku_arr;
}
void    ft_print_sudoku(int **sudoku)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 9)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j < 9)
        {
            printf("%d ", sudoku[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ft_print_sudoku(ft_copy_sudoku(argc, argv));
    return (0);
}
```

When debugging with the gdb, i got the following message.

```
    Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x000000000004007a6 in ft_print_sudoku (sudoku=0x1060420) at puzzle.c:62
62 j++;
```

Comment: And line `puzzle.c:62` is which please?

Comment: It was the last line in my post. j++;. I removed that one, and now the problematic line is the 39-th one. sudoku_arr[s_index][j] = argv[index][j];

Comment: a debugger should be able to tell you more than that, not only the line where the fault occurred but also you could print the contents of all your variablles, e.g `j`, to know exactly *when* your program crashes.

Comment: Your multi-level indirection in this is completely wrong. You're allocating space for 81 `int` values. Just because you save the result from `malloc` as `int**` doesn't mean you can treat that allocation like an array of pointers; it is no such thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going on the assumption that your command line parameters are sequences of digits+markers in sets of nine chars per (and you have up to nine of these) It appears you're trying to allocate a dynamic table of 9x9 `int` values to store those digits.

Your code as last-posted is using incorrect indirection. You're declaring an `int**`, setting it to `malloc(9*9*sizeof(int))`, then treating it as an array of pointers, which it is *not*.

If you want to use a pointer to an array of 9-`int`, then use an appropriate pointer-to-type to reflect that. Such a pointer looks like this:

```
int (*ptr)[9];
```

Using that, you can craft your function to allocate a sequence of `9` elements of that pointed-to type:

```
int (*arr)[DIM] = calloc(DIM, sizeof *arr);
```

where `DIM` is the table dimension you're allocating, known at compile-time, in this case `9`. The last oddity is the method for returning such a thing from your function, which can be done any number of ways. One way, though having a infrequently used syntax, looks like this:

```
int (*ft_copy_sudoku(int argc, char **argv))[DIM]
{
    int (*arr)[DIM] = calloc(DIM, sizeof *arr);

    .... code ....

    return arr;
}
```

Another arguably clearer way uses a `typedef` for the pointer-to-array-of-DIM-int :

```
typedef int (*row_ptr)[DIM];

row_ptr ft_copy_sudoku(int argc, char **argv)
{
    row_ptr arr = calloc(DIM, sizeof *arr);

    .... code ....

    return arr;
}
```

---

**Putting It Together**

Taking in all of that, the result looks something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIM  9

int (*ft_copy_sudoku(int argc, char **argv))[DIM]
{
    int (*arr)[DIM] = calloc(DIM, sizeof *arr);
    int ridx, cidx;

    for (ridx=1; ridx < argc && ridx <= DIM; ++ridx)
    {
        char *row = argv[ridx];
        for (cidx=0; *row && cidx < DIM; ++cidx, ++row)
        {
            if (*row >= '1' && *row <= '9')
                arr[ridx-1][cidx] = *row - '0';
        }
    }
    return arr;
}


void ft_print_sudoku(int (* const arr)[DIM])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<DIM; ++i)
    {
        for (j=0; j<DIM; ++j)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        putc('\n', stdout);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int (*sudoku)[DIM] = ft_copy_sudoku(argc, argv);
    ft_print_sudoku(sudoku);
    free(sudoku);
    return 0;
}
```

An example of this with a stack of 9 command line args of digits and markers [can be seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81d9b50db910f11d). The example command line with arguments and printed output are presented below:

```
./a.out 123-567-9 234-67891 3-5678-1- ---789123 5-7-9-2-4 67-9123-5 78-12345- 8-123-567 -1-3-5-7-

1 2 3 0 5 6 7 0 9 
2 3 4 0 6 7 8 9 1 
3 0 5 6 7 8 0 1 0 
0 0 0 7 8 9 1 2 3 
5 0 7 0 9 0 2 0 4 
6 7 0 9 1 2 3 0 5 
7 8 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 
8 0 1 2 3 0 5 6 7 
0 1 0 3 0 5 0 7 0
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error. Your help is much appreciated.